# Installing SharePoint 2013 Enterprise edition on Windows Server 2012 R2 gives error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error, installation, prerequisites

I am trying to install SharePoint 2013 on a machine where I have Windows Server 2012 R2 OS.
When I run the software prerequisites installer, it gives me an error which says that -

"the tool was unable to install application server role web server (iis) role sharepoint 2013"

I have added roles in the server manager on the server. Along with that I have also tried a few options from two three blogs but no success.

One link that I got repeatedly in my search is [this](https://sharelockpoint.wordpress.com/2013/09/09/sharepoint-2013-pre-requisites-install-fail-error-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web-server-iis-role/). I followed the given steps but got no success.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: did you install the prerequisites softwares?

Comment: Are you using SP1 media?
Was the .net 3.5 role installed sucessfully? (you sometimes need to point it to the Windows ISO)

Comment: I get this error when I run the install prerequisites option from SharePoint 2013 installation file.

Comment: Make sure you are running the SP1 installation (it is required for Windows 2012R2) and try to manually install the .net 3.5 feature before running the prerequisites installer

Comment: How can I manually install .net 3.5 feature? Please guide me on that.

Comment: Try the Powershell **"dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /Source:d:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess"** from  [this blog](http://www.danielclasson.com/install-net-framework-35-server-2012/) and if it fails, try the GUI installation(also on the blog)

Comment: I forgot to mention, you will need the Windows installation DVD in the D drive for the command above

Comment: I already have .net 3.5 installed. I checked it in the features section of server manager. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19377/discussion-between-mancydesaee-and-choggo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SP 2013 exe installer needs a file named servermanagercmd.exe, which is not present in the windows server 2012 R2 OS. So we need to rename the file servermanager.exe, to servermanagercmd.exe which is located in windows\system32 directory.

This is what has solved my problem.